# how to fix the encryption not giving the correct message for words

Tags: vb.net

my code is not giving the correct output for a Caesar cipher when i type in a word.

```
 Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

 Function Encrypt() As String

    Dim Key As Integer
    Dim message As String
    Dim encmessage As String

    Console.Write("enter the message to be encrypted")
    message = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim LetterArray() As Char = message.ToCharArray
    Console.Write("what key would you like to use?")
    Key = Console.ReadLine()

    For i = 0 To LetterArray.Length - 1
        encmessage &= Chr(Asc(LetterArray) + Key)
    Next

    Return encmessage

 End Function

 End Module
```

when i type a letter it gives me the correct encryption but when i type a word it gives the incorrect encryption.
e.g
when i type hello with a key of two it gives me the output of jjjjj.

Comment: give examples of your output

Comment: when i type hello with a key of two it gives me the output of jjjjj

Comment: `Asc(LetterArray)` doesn’t make sense; `Asc(LetterArray(i))` is closer. `Option Strict` *probably* prevents that? Always turn it on project-wide.

Comment: @Ry, it may be valid syntax if it passes as a string as `Asc` accepts both strings and char. If it's a string only the first character is used for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a string to `Asc`, only the first character of the string is used for input. See the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Strings_Asc_System_String_). To process each character, you have to pass them in individually using the index position:

```
For i = 0 To LetterArray.Length - 1
    encmessage &= Chr(Asc(LetterArray(i)) + Key)
```